# When do you determine whether project will use sequential phase-to-phase manner or as a overlapping phase manner for project management?

Tags: planning, scheduling, time-management, pmp

Is determining if a project is going to executed in a sequential phase-to-phase manner or as a overlapping phase (fast-tracking) manner done in Project Management plan( and/or one of it's subsidiary plans)  or is it determined during one of the processes in the Project Time Management Knowledge area?

List of processes in the Project Time Management Knowledge area

1)  Activity Definition process.

2)   Activity Sequencing process

3)   Activity Resource Estimating process

4)   Activity Duration Estimating process

5)   Schedule Development process

Answer (score 2):

according to PMBOK, it is done in the 'develop project management plan' in the planning / integration management part. methodology for running the project should be taken into consideration before planning for other activities.

Answer (score 2):

Fast tracking is a risk response.  It is a costly mitigation designed to recover unfavorable schedule and finish variances.  Therefore, the determination of fast tracking would occur in the Project Risk Management Knowledge Area within the Planning Process Group.  Many of the other Planning Process Group processes would be invoked to carry out this intervention, but it initially begins with risk management.